# Error Destroying Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    private string hitobject;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetButtonUp ("Jump")) {
            Debug.Log("SPACE");
            Rigidbody r = GameObject.Find("trigger").AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            r.mass = 3f;
        }
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision myCollision)
    {
        hitobject = myCollision.gameObject.tag;
        if (hitobject == "wall")
        {
            Destroy(hitobject);
        }
    }
}
```

Whats the problem?

Error says:

> Assets/NewBehaviourScript.cs(20,25): error CS1502: The best overloaded
>   method match for `UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(UnityEngine.Object)' has
>   some invalid arguments
>
> Assets/NewBehaviourScript.cs(20,25): error CS1503: Argument `#1'
>   cannot convert`string' expression to type `UnityEngine.Object'

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to destroy the tag instead of the GameObject.

You can fix it like this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision myCollision)
{
    GameObject g = myCollision.gameObject;        

    if(g.tag == "wall")
       Destroy(g);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we changed `string` to `gameobject` so we can destroy the gameobject not a string and use the tag one of its properties(vars) to check what we hit

```
 private GameObject hitobject ; 
 void OnCollisionEnter(Collision myCollision)
 {
   hitobject = myCollision.gameObject;
    if (hitobject.tag == "wall")
      {
       Destroy(hitobject);
      }

}
```

Comment: That won't work, `private string hit object;`, you can't store a GameObject inside a string.